# provide extra return column of boolean type which evaluates another query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am trying to develop a query that will

1. Give the last message in every thread that was not written by the currentUserID (right now accomplished with group by thread_id, order by message_id desc AND WHERE results.sender_id != currentUserID)
2. If the user started a thread but received no response then the thread should not show up (right now accomplished by simply filtering the data with WHERE results.sender_id != currentUserID)
3. Provide a boolean column to tell if a response was sent in this thread (not accomplished but would involve finding the last element from the query and seeing if the sender_id is = to current logged in user id)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85971/2

**Synopsis**

- User 1 sends a message with User 2 with
- Thread ID: 1
- Subject: 'Hi Subject'
- Body: 'Hi Body'
- User 2 responds:
- Thread ID: 1
- Body: 'Hi Body Response'

**As User 1 the SQL Should Return**

```
THREAD_ID |SUBJECT     | SENDER_ID | BODY             | Responded
1         | Hi Subject | 2         | Hi Body Response | false
```

**As User 2 the SQL Should Return**

```
THREAD_ID |SUBJECT     | SENDER_ID | BODY    | Responded
1         | Hi Subject | 1         | Hi Body | true
```

Please see fiddle

My shot at it was the following which takes acre of 1 and 2 but not 3, I tried to mess around with UNIONS to achieve this but got nowhere.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.id as thread_id, t.subject, m.sender_id, m.body
    FROM messages m
    JOIN threads t ON (m.thread_id = t.id)
    ORDER BY t.id asc, m.cdate desc
) as results
WHERE results.sender_id != currentUserID
GROUP BY results.thread_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the queries below. I also added the message ID column.

First Result ...

```
SELECT t.id as thread_id, t.subject, m.sender_id, m.body, m.id,
(SELECT CASE s.status WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 
 FROM STATUS s where s.message_id = m.id and s.user_id = 1) Responded
FROM messages m
JOIN threads t ON (m.thread_id = t.id)
WHERE m.sender_id != 1
```

Second one...

```
SELECT t.id as thread_id, t.subject, m.sender_id, m.body, m.id,
(SELECT CASE s.status WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 
 FROM STATUS s where s.message_id = m.id and s.user_id = 2) Responded
FROM messages m
JOIN threads t ON (m.thread_id = t.id)
WHERE m.sender_id != 2
```

Thanks!

@leo.